# Salesforce Integration with external website using REST API

Tags: visualforce, rest-api, apexrest, website-integration

I want to integrate my salesforce instance with some external website (Having Its own api)by using REST API where I have to authecticate myself/my_application with the external website by using key assigned by external website.

How Can I do this? 
I want to know the steps required to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the website developed in ?

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question - what is the website? Does it use a standard, such as OAuth?

Comment: Website is CompaniesHouse.gov.uk from where I want to get information about companies and their financial records like annual revenue etc..
The website uses standard as I cant get information without authentication of me from companiesHouse API.